# Electrical Work Question

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, vent, electrical-panel, junction-box

We had an electrician move our breaker box. He put in a junction box and ran a 100 amp cord, along with other wires next to one of our air vents. Is this to code?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

We worry that even if it is framed around that if somebody tries to put a nail in for some reason and it goes into the 100 amp cord they will die almost immediately. When the electrician was questioned he stated it was fine because we were going to drywall over it. I added pictures of the cords next to the vent as well as some of his other work. How does it all look?

Thanks!

Comment: It only takes about 0.1A of current to kill someone, so whether the nail goes through a 100A cable or a 15A cable, they both have the same potential to kill someone so you should be equally worried about all of the wiring, not just the new one. I don't know the relevant codes, but I don't think that what he's done is out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of the wires are closer than 1-1/4" from the surface of the stud it requires a steel plate to protect the wire. If the hole is 1-1/4" from the face of the stud it is 100% code legal.